# How can I fix the title height in mdframed boxes?

Tags: mdframed, height, frame-title

I am trying to write a LaTeX document involving a lot of definitions. For this reason, I decided to create a `mdframed` environment (see below), and place my definitions one after the other in a two-column environment.

```
\newmdenv[%
    frametitleaboveskip=5pt, frametitlebelowskip=5pt,
    backgroundcolor=white,frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=black!20,linewidth=1pt,
    frametitlefont=\ttfamily
]{numframed}
```

Basically, this gives me a simple titled box, with a gray header, and a white background for the definition itself. However, I noticed that the height of my gray headers varies. This is particularly annoying when the second column receives its first definition:

```
\begin{multicols*}{2}
    \begin{numframed}[frametitle=Text with letters going below line]
    \end{numframed}

    % ... other definitions until the end of the first column

    \begin{numframed}[frametitle=Text without these letters]
    \end{numframed}
\end{multicols*}
```

[image: mdframed titles with irregular height]

As you can see, in the first column, the first definition's title contains letters which go "below the line" : the g's. There is no such letter in the first definition of the second column. In each case, LaTeX naturally fits the container to the content.

Now, having these two boxes, one next to the other, and getting misaligned title headers really annoys me. Would there be a way for me to fix the title header's height (and possibly set vertical alignment to center afterwards) in order to align my header areas completely?

Comment: Did you try `minimum height=1.5em` for example?

Comment: @Sigur It does not appear to be a valid parameter when defining an environment (`titledframe`). Wouldn't it apply to the entire box instead of just the title? I've never manipulated TikZ parameters before.

Comment: Add a `\strut` to the title,as in `frametitle={\strut The title text\strut}`. I'm writing an answer in which this is done automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `\strut` for the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newmdenv[%
    frametitleaboveskip=5pt, frametitlebelowskip=5pt,
    backgroundcolor=white,frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=black!20,linewidth=1pt,
    frametitlefont=\ttfamily,
    ]{numframedi}
\newenvironment{numframed}[2][]
  {\begin{numframedi}[#1,frametitle={\strut#2\strut}]}
  {\end{numframedi}}    

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{numframed}{Text with descenders py}
    \end{numframed}
    \begin{numframed}{Text with no descenders in two lines}
    \end{numframed}
    \begin{numframed}{Text with no descenders}
    \end{numframed}
    \begin{numframed}{Text with descenders in two lines py}
    \end{numframed}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The new syntax for `numframed` is

```
\begin{numframed}[<options to mdframed>]{<title>}
(...contents...)
\end{numframed}
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) I simplified it a little by removing the options passed to `mdframed` by `numframed`, since they will not be necessary in my document.